# if two consecutive characters are same it adds the character in the list and if the string contains no duplicate characters it adds a 'x' to the list

Tags: python

Iterate a given list of strings for each item, so that if two consecutive characters are same it adds the character and the count of the character in the result list and if the string/item contains no duplicate characters it adds an 'x' to the result list.

This needs to be solved without any user defined-functions or oops concepts.

```
list1=['occur','madam']
i = 0
s=''
s1=''
l2=[]
for index in range(len(list1)):
    s=list1[index]
    while(i<len(s)-1):
        count=1
        if s[i]==s[i+1]:
            count+=1
            s1=s[i]+str(count)
            l2.append(s1)
        else:
            l2.append('x')
        i+=1
        count+=1
        if i+1==len(s):
            break
    print(l2)    
    index+=1
```

output expected for this given input `list1=['occur','madam' ]  resultList=['c2','x']` where `c2` is for occur and `x` is for madam.

the output I'm getting:

```
['x', 'c2', 'x', 'x']
['x', 'c2', 'x', 'x']
```

Comment: There is no `resultList` in your code.

Comment: l2[] serves the purpose.

Comment: What if `list1=['xaaax','aabbaa']`?

Comment: i guess it shouldn't matter, it should work for them as well giving  us['a3' | 'a2','b2','a2']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't clear how to handle strings w/ multiple runs (`['a3' | 'a2','b2','a2']` isn't a valid python list), but this should be close:

```
import re
list1=['occur','madam','xaaax','aabbaa']
result = []
for line in list1:
    m = re.findall(r'(.)(\1+)',line)
    if m:
        result += ["%s%d"%(x[0],1+len(x[1])) for x in m]
    else:
        result += ['x']
print(result)
```

will produce

```
['c2', 'x', 'a3', 'a2, 'b2', 'a2']
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. The `else` block adds 'x' to the `l2` list **every time a letter is different**. Instead, you need to wait for the `while` loop to finish and only then check if `l2` is empty or not.
2. You need to re-initialize `l2` to a new array every time you start a new string, otherwise it will remember the one of the previous string and will keep adding to it.

Corrected code:

```py
list1=['occur','madam']
i = 0
s=''
s1=''
for index in range(len(list1)):
    s=list1[index]
    l2=[]
    while(i<len(s)-1):
        count=1
        if s[i]==s[i+1]:
            count+=1
            s1=s[i]+str(count)
            l2.append(s1)
        i+=1
        count+=1
        if i+1==len(s):
            break
    if len(l2) == 0:
        l2.append('x')
    print(l2)    
    index+=1
```

Comment: hey, thanx for the suggestion but it's not giving the desired results.